# Infinite period in Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I'm studying the Simple Harmonic Motion, and I am hesitant about, how to get mass values for infinite period?

- When mass is 0.
- When mass is infinite.

With $\tau=2\pi/\sqrt{k/m}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because if you have zero mass you can't use the Newtonian $F=m a$ to find force, you'll have a hard time making a physical argument for having zero mass. Likewise, you break all physical barriers when you go to an infinite mass. The best one can do is say that the mass *approaches* zero or *approaches* infinity.

As $m\to \infty$, $\frac{m}{k}\to \infty$, and so the period goes to infinity, which can be physically interpreted as the spring's $k$ constant is just not strong enough to accelerate the mass *at all*.

As $m\to 0$, $\frac{m}{k}\to 0$, and so the period goes to zero, which can be physically interpreted as very very fast vibrations.

The trick used here is the same one used in $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ limit/derivative proofs in pure math. To avoid the problem of calculating $\infty-\infty$ or $\infty/\infty$, we just calculate behavior "arbitrarily large" or "arbitrarily small", but not *actually* infinite nor zero.

Comment: Besides, in physics "arbitrarily small" is usually just as good as zero, since eventually you go below the resolution of your instrument.